# AND search returns OR results on Lucene .net

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

When I search for 'chicken soup'. I get results which contain 'chicken' , 'soup' or both of them.

I have tried the following search queries and they all return the same results:

- `"chicken"AND"soup"`
- `+chicken +soup`

Here is the code I use, please help:

```
private DataTable SearchDishName(string textSearch)
{
    string MatchingCutomisationIDs = "0"; //There is no Dish with ID zero, this is just to easen the coding.. 
    var ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_data/MyDataset.xml"));
    DataTable Sample = new DataTable();
    Sample = ds.Tables[0];
    var table = Sample.Clone();
    var Index = createIndex(Sample);
    using (var reader = IndexReader.Open(Index, true))
    using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader))
    {
        using (Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30))
        {
            var queryParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "DishName", analyzer);
            var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(1000, true);
            try
            {
                var query = queryParser.Parse(textSearch);
                searcher.Search(query, collector);
            }
            catch
            { }
            var matches = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
            foreach (var item in matches)
            {
                var id = item.Doc;
                var doc = searcher.Doc(id);
                var row = table.NewRow();
                row["CustomisationID"] = doc.GetField("CustomisationID").StringValue;
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }
    return table;
}

Directory createIndex(DataTable table)
{
    var directory = new RAMDirectory();

    using (Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30))
    using (var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(1000)))
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            var document = new Document();
            document.Add(new Field("DishName", row["YouTubeTitle"].ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new Field("CustomisationID", row["CustomisationID"].ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

            writer.AddDocument(document);
        }

        writer.Optimize();
        writer.Flush(true, true, true);
    }
    return directory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok, should work. I refactored it a bit into a full test (green). Several different versions of the AND query all just return the one, correct doc. Can't see much difference with your code. Maybe you can see some difference with where you cut the sample out off?

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest3
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestLucene()
    {
        var writer = CreateIndex();
        AddDish(writer, "chicken soup", "1");
        AddDish(writer, "veg soup", "2");
        AddDish(writer, "chicken balti", "3");
        writer.Flush(true, true, true);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, writer.NumDocs());

        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(writer.GetReader());
        Search(searcher, "chicken AND soup");
        Search(searcher, "\"chicken\" AND \"soup\"");
        Search(searcher, "+chicken +soup");

        writer.Dispose();
    }

    private void Search(IndexSearcher searcher, string query)
    {
        var result = SearchDishName(searcher, query);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("1", result[0]);
    }

    private List<string> SearchDishName(IndexSearcher searcher, string textSearch)
    {
        using (var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30))
        {
            var queryParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "DishName", analyzer);
            var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(1000, true);
            var query = queryParser.Parse(textSearch);
            searcher.Search(query, collector);

            var result = new List<string>();
            var matches = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
            foreach (var item in matches)
            {
                var id = item.Doc;
                var doc = searcher.Doc(id);
                result.Add(doc.GetField("CustomisationID").StringValue);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    IndexWriter CreateIndex()
    {
        var directory = new RAMDirectory();

        var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
        var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(1000));

        return writer;
    }
    void AddDish(IndexWriter writer, string dishname, string id)
    {
        var document = new Document();
        document.Add(new Field("DishName", dishname, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        document.Add(new Field("CustomisationID", id, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

        writer.AddDocument(document);
    }
}
```